# Debian 10: Selenium firefox_driver incompatible with Firefox ESR

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

In Debian 10, the firefox_driver is removed from Synaptic because of incompatibility with Firefox ESR. I downloaded latest geckodriver from GitHub, plus installed latest Firefox (using flatpak). I get this error message calling webdriver.Firefox():

```
SessionNotCreatedException: Unable to find a matching set of capabilities
```

How can I run firefox from Python?

Versions

```
Firefox 80.0.1 (installed from flatpak)
geckodriver 0.27 (in /usr/local/bin/)
Selenium,3.14.1
Python 3.7.3
```

Script:

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("http://www.python.org")
assert "Python" in driver.title
```

Comment: I had the same problem and downgrading firefox to 68.12.0 fixed my problem.

BTW. I'm not sure why the moderator removed my comment and it sucks I'm not able to do anything about that... Still, I think it is useful information: that I have the same problem (read I can reproduce this problem) and I've tried the recent git version, selenium-4.0.0.a6-py2.py3-none-any.whl, and that did not helped. Also, I've tried a newer version of geckodriver v.0.27.0 but that did not helped as well.

I've opened upstream bug report: https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/8709

Comment: After I've upgraded firefox to 82.0 everything works as expected.